# Kibana is not using the elasticsearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, logstash, kibana

I am using logstash/elasticsearch/kibana to keep some application logs under control.
The application I am working on is custom development so I had to define my patterns/extra file and my own elasticsearch mapping.

The mapping I defined is:

```
{
    "http-logs": {
        "properties": {
            "message": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no"
            },
            "@version": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "command": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "analyzed"
            },
            "facade-in": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "facade-out": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "elapsed": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "items": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and once loaded on ES, I can see it defined as expected:
    ...
        "command" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
    ...

After loading my logs with logstash I am trying to visualize some data but playing aroud with my fields I am puzzled as kibana is saying that my command is analyzed....whereas it should not be.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you update the mappings when the index was empty? You can't change the mappings when there already are documents of that type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did update the index but an additional missing step was refreshing the kibana's setting. Not doing so my old analyzed attributes did not move.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924248/how-to-stop-logstash-from-creating-a-default-mapping-in-elasticsearch) logstash will not rely on your mapping if your documents are not matching it. Doublechecking my objects and my definition the differences caused the problem and cleaning my mapping/objects up did the trick.